# How did the powers of Gods change from Rig Veda to the puranas?

Tags: puranas, gods, rig-veda, war

In particular, I am interested in mobility and war making.  Puranas depict supernatural mobility (flying machines with no energy-source mentioned, Hanuman, Kartikeya going round the world, varaha carrying the whole earth) and of course weapons which are described as being capable of ending the whole world.

As far as I know, Rig Veda mostly depicts ordinary human mobility (vishnu's three steps only describing the sun) and only slightly exaggerated powers of war-making.

Comment: If it is true that it is only in India that Gods "powered up" enormously after the earliest period - thats evidence for Aryan immigration to India.  The simple myths of incoming Aryans became unimaginably fantastic, often removed from laws of science on contact with Dravidians.  This ties in very nicely with linguistic evidence - so many Vedic words that died out in later Sanskrit but have parallel in Latin and Greek - the Vedic verb system closely paralleling Greek but getting drastically simplified in later Sanskrit.